# WrapMode issue with international language

Tags: qt, unicode, qml, qt5

I am having an issue with wrapping text in a QML Text element for international language such as korean .

```
Text {
    text: "안녕하세요 반갑습니다"
    width: 100
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
}
```

If I run this code, the text is displayed like this:

```
안녕하세요 반갑습
니다.
```

As you can see, the line breaks at the end of the third character of the second word. However, what I want is to break into a new line at the end of a word, not in the middle of a word. The proper output should be like this:

```
안녕하세요 
반갑습니다.
```

Is there any way to solve this out? I am currently using Qt 5.1.1.

Comment: See this post http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4897/P15.

Comment: I've already seen that post. I am not considering to use WebView element.

Answer (score 3):

Read [Unicode documentation about word bouderies](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Word_Boundaries). This behavior is proper (there is Korean-English example). Read this carefully maybe you will find satisfying solution.

In Unicode there is spatial [character `WJ` (Word Joiner)](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/#WJ). You can use this to fix it.

[This also (`JL`)](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/#JL) looks interesting (Korean Korean syllable blocks).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried the word joiner(WJ) which is "\u2060", but it prints a square symbol. I can't figure out how to apply JL.